# SEF url without passing id

Tags: sef

Client need SEF URL for e-commerce site (ISS 6). We tried `IonicIsapiRewriter` and it works good.

Now consider the below url,

```
www.store.com/product/12345/men_tshirt.html
```

This works fine. I write the rule to pass the id as query string (product.action?prt_id=12345)

But client wants the URL to be

```
www.store.com/product/men_tshirt.html
```

How to do this? Without passing product id how to identify the product?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get this working as expected, the `men_tshirt` part needs to be the new ID to identify the resource that was formerly identified by `12345`. So `men_tshirt` needs to be a unique value in that context.

Then you just need a mapping of those textual IDs onto numeric ID.

Comment: Thanks Gumbo. Not sure we can implement(quickly) in this framework.Every where the products is referenced with their id.